# Should you check runTimeType of variables in fromJson functions as best practice?

Tags: flutter

Pretty basic question, but wondering what the best practice is and can't seem to find any references to this on SO or elsewhere.

Should you check the runTimeType of properties before you attempt to store them when you parse fromJson even if you are confident it should never be anything but the type you think, or null? Or do we just accept the error if this highly unlikely event ever happens?

Thanks !

```
factory SomeClass.fromJson(Map data) {
    if (data == null) return null;

String someString = data['someString']; //no runTimeType check
int someInt = data['someInt']; //no runTimeType check


 try {
      assert(someString != null, 'Some String was null in Some Class Json');
      assert(someInt != null,
          'Some Int null in Some Class Json');
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }

   
return SomeClass(someString: someString, someInt: someInt); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be really nice to check the runtime type of the variable as well, as it will prevent any potential app crash when the database is updated in the future.

As far as the `null` checks are concerned, I personally pass in a default value like for `String` I store an empty string as the default value instead of `null`.

```
String someString = data['someString'] ?? '';
```

Even if the database returns a `null` value, our app should be able to handle those conditions.

The most common type of error that I've personally experienced is during the parsing of data. Type `String` is not a subtype of `int`. Something like that. So, I guess it would be nice to check the runtime types of values returned from the backend.

Comment: So add if (data['someString'].runTimeType == String) { unwrap here } to every property?